# Image segmentation - Input label dictionary alongside mask to keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, image-segmentation

My training data consists of a number of images each with a single mask. This mask contains a number of classes each represented by separate colour.

How can I associate each colour with a label in a way such that I can input it to my model alongside the image and the mask.

I have a dictionary that associate each colour with a label. Like so:

```
LFW_PARTS_PALETTE = {
    (0, 0, 0) : 0 , 
    (0, 148, 218) : 1 , 
    (90, 90, 90) : 2 , 
    (52,124,49) : 3 , 
    (52,52,255) : 4 , 
    (52,52,137) : 5 , 
    (0,255,255) : 6 , 
    (143,71,143) : 7 , 
    (255,255,255) : 8 , 
    (119,43,43) : 9 , 
    (165,148,44) : 10 , 
}
```